# Resharper Inspect Code and Code Analysis Plugin are not in sync

Tags: resharper, jetbrains-ide

I am using resharper code inspection plugin for development code analysis.
And I am using Resharper inspectcode command line tool to generate the report for the code issues from the build machine. I am using the default settings for provided by resharper both of them.

What I have noticed is in development machine there are no errors but when you run the report via inspectcode command line tool from build machine
there are plenty of errors identified by typeid = C#SharpErrors category = C# Compiler Errrors.

Snippet from Intermediate Resharper XML

And I have understood from the link https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/Reference__Options__Code_Inspection__Inspection_Severity.html?origin=old_help we cannot suppress these errors from custom dotsettings file for report generated via inspectcode.

What I would like to know, why the same default error is not seen in development machine?
Is there any thing I need to configure to enable this default compiler errors detected by Resharper code Analysis from development machine?
Or is there way to suppress these C#SharpErrors detected by Resharper even though visual studio didn't catch it?

Thanks
Murali

Comment: What compile errors are you seeing? Are these being run on the same machine? Do the different machines have different versions of .net/compilers installed?

Comment: Code inspection plugin runs on developer's machine and the inspectcode command line tool generating the report runs on build machine (2 diff machines). For a particular csharp file there were no resharper errors on dev machine, but the same when run on the build machine generates the report with some errors as mentioned above categorized by "CSharpErrors"

Comment: Can you give an example of the compiler error? Is it failing to resolve methods and types, or failing to compile a C#6 construct?

Comment: Thanks for your help citizenmatt.pls find the link for the sample app which demonstrates this problem. https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2L8InUrojNvb0hqcWl4VV9jUHc&usp=sharing also attached result XML from inspectcode tool. Pls open the project in vs2012 with code inspection plugin installed on it. you will notice there are suggestions and warnings but there are no errors. but the same code base run through inspect code command line tool you will get the attached result xml

Comment: The errors are complaining that you're using a C# 3 feature (auto properties, I think) that aren't supported by the current build tools. Can you confirm that your build machine has up to date compilers and msbuild?

Comment: Thanks citizenmatt. I will verify this and post my findings.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have a similar problem with latest version of inspectcode 2020.3.1, we run this on our CI server and developers run ReSHarper analysis on their visual studio. the results vary for same code checked out and compiled.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was due to the fact that my IDE was running a different version of ReSharper than the command line tool. Check this if that is your case: [ReSharper Versions](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/other.html)